# Local DNS server responds with SERVFAIL

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I followed [this](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/09/19/setting-up-internal-dns-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/) guide to set up a DNS on my local network. I've properly set up the home.local. domain. My nameserver has the ip 192.168.2.16 and has an A record named maxdator.home.local pointing to it.

Now I'm trying to add another zone called festmedhest.se, but the server always responds with SERVFAIL when I run host -l festmedhest.se or nslookup test.festmedhest.se (2)

**cat zones/festmedhest.se.db**

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400 ; 1 day

@ IN SOA maxdator.home.local. admin.home.local. (
 2015030512 ; serial
 8H ; refresh
 4H ; retry
 4W ; expire
 1D ; minimum
)

@ IN NS maxdator.home.local.

$ORIGIN festmedhest.se.


; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
test IN A 192.168.2.1
```

**cat named.conf.local**

```
zone "home.local" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/home.local.db";
};

zone "festmedhest.se" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/festmedhest.se.db";
};

zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
 type master;
 file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

**cat named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

I've tried to replace maxdator.home.local with 192.168.2.16 but nothing changes. (I'm guessing i'm doing something wrong with SOA or or NS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`named-checkconf -zj` or reading your logs should reveal the reason for the `SERVFAIL` problem.

In this case it appears that the `SOA` record in the zone file for your `festmedhest.se` is outside the zone.

Answer (score 1):

works when I removed *$ORIGIN .* from festmedhest.se.db.